# Helm template entire YAML section as JSON configmap

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to pass an entire YAML stanza as a JSON config mapped file into my service. A simple example is

values.yaml:

```yaml
serviceName: "mySuperCoolService"

configMaps:
  - filename: "file1.json"
    content: "{{ .Values.content1 }}"
  - filename: "file2.json"
    content: "{{ .Values.content2 }}"

content1:
  field1: "value1"
  field2:
    field3: "value3"
    field4: "value4"

content2:
  field5: "value5"
  field6:
    field7: "value7"
    field8: "value8"
```

templates/configmap.yaml:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.serviceName }}-jsonConfigMap
data:
  {{- range .Values.configMaps }}
  {{ .filename }}: | 
  {{ tpl .content $ | toPrettyJson | indent 4}}
  {{- end }}
```

My desired output for the `configmap.yaml` template would be:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mySuperCoolService-jsonConfigMap
data:
  file1.json: | 
    {
      "field1": "value1",
      "field2":
      {
        "field3": "value3",
        "field4": "value4"
      }
    }
  file2.json: | 
    {
      "field5": "value5",
      "field6":
      {
        "field7": "value7",
        "field8": "value8"
      }
    }
```

However no matter what various things I try it always seems to come out:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mySuperCoolService-jsonConfigMap
data:
  file1.json: | 
      "map[field1:value1 field2:map[field3:value3 field4:value4]]"
  file2.json: | 
      "map[field5:value5 field6:map[field7:value7 field8:value8]]"
```

How to I convert the map type object into actual JSON?

Comment: Apparently, `tpl` seems to be working only for strings and not for objects. Not sure if 
 [`tpl`](https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-tpl-function) function is supposed to work for objects as well. If it s then it surely is a bug. You might want to open an issue on the [helm](https://github.com/helm/helm) repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of aspects of the Go `text/template` language are very oriented around strings.  A `{{ ... }}` double-brace expression always evaluates to a string; in Helm more specifically, `include` and `tpl` always return strings.  If maps or lists are returned here, they get converted back to a string using a default Go serialization, which is the `map[key:value]` syntax you see.

The most direct answer to this is to make sure, when you include part of the values inside a template expression, that you serialize it to JSON there:

```yaml
configMaps:
  - filename: "file1.json"
    content: "{{ .Values.content1 | toPrettyJson }}"
  - filename: "file2.json"
    content: "{{ .Values.content2 | toPrettyJson }}"
```

```yaml
{{ tpl .content $ | indent 4}}
```

I wonder if you're trying to make the configuration too flexible, though.  What you have shown as configuration closely mirrors the structure of a Kubernetes ConfigMap, to the point where just writing out a ConfigMap YAML wouldn't actually be more difficult.  Putting keys in a ConfigMap on its own isn't useful unless a Pod knows to access them.  It might make more sense to enumerate the specific known ConfigMap keys in your template file, which in this particular case would remove `tpl` entirely

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-jsonConfigMap
data:
  file1.json: |
{{ .Values.content1 | toPrettyJson | indent 4 }}
  file2.json: |
{{ .Values.content2 | toPrettyJson | indent 4 }}
```

Or even to put the core of the JSON structure in your template code, and take more specific configuration values where needed:

```yaml
data:
  file1.json: |
    {
      "field1": {
        "field2": {{ .Values.frobnicationLevel | toJson }}
      }
    }
```